# Is there a safe way to show an error notification page when the script crashes?

Tags: php

Like one of those "Error 404" pages, I wish to show the visitor an error page with a fat sorry message in the case a script crashes. I use register_shutdown_function() to register a callback function. But the problem is, probably, that headers were already sent. However, maybe you know a good possibility to do that?

Comment: In theory, your scripts should not just "crash" (or it should be something really really **rare**) : you should handle errors more graciously than by crashing -- detecting errors (like failure to connect to the database server) and throwing an exception, catched later (with the catch block showing some kind of nice error page), might be a solution -- but no need to detect "crashes", here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this blog post may be helpful: http://www.eggplant.ws/blog/php/mayday-php-going-down/

The author shows how to catch fatal errors and deal with them gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set_error_handler is what you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php